# Unable to create a MySQL database backup in GCP storage

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, devops, kubernetes-cronjob

We deploy a laravel project in k8s(GCP) with mysql database. Now i want time to time backup of this database with the help of cronjob and I followed an [articles](https://medium.com/searce/cronjob-to-backup-mysql-on-gke-23bb706d9bbf)  but i'm unable to create a backup file. However, as per article we need to create the storage bucket and service account in [GCP](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en)

It is working properly still there is no backup file in storage bucket.

cronjob.yaml file

`apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: backup-cronjob
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: backup-container
            image: gcr.io/thereport/abcd
            env:
              - name: DB_NAME
                valueFrom:
                  configMapKeyRef:
                    name: backup-configmap
                    key: db
              - name: GCS_BUCKET
                valueFrom:
                  configMapKeyRef:
                    name: backup-configmap
                    key: gcs-bucket
              - name: DB_HOST
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: backup
                    key: db_host
              - name: DB_USER
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: backup
                    key: username
              - name: DB_PASS
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: backup
                    key: password
              - name: GCS_SA
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: backup
                    key: thereport-541be75e66dd.json
            args:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - mysqldump --u root --p"root" homestead > trydata.sql; gcloud config set project thereport; gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file backup; gsutil cp /trydata.sql gs://backup-buck`

```
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Hello, do your kube service account have access to write objects in your bucket? for a quick try (not for real implementation) make your [bucket public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets) and try to run the job, if you see the dump file in your bucket after this you will need to take a look at your bucket policy to give access to your kube.

Answer (score 1):

You don't copy the right file:

> mysqldump --u root --p"root" homestead > **trydata.sql**; gcloud config set project thereport; gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file backup; gsutil cp **/laravel.sql** gs://backup-buck

Comment: To be sure that you get the same file, in the same directory, try with this (absolute path to trydata.sql file because you copy the file with this path) ` mysqldump --u root --p"root" homestead > /trydata.sql;`

Comment: i have done everything as per suggestion, still not able to take backup.